# Convex function and Jensens inequality

Tags: probability, expectation

I have an exercise, which I don't know how to solve.

Given that the random variable $X>0$, such that $P(X\leq 0)=0$. Argue that 
$ E(\frac{1}{X})\geq \frac{1}{E(X)}$.

My first question is, how can I know if a function is convex or concave, in this case 
$\frac{1}{x}$. If I figure out if this function is convex or concave I can apply the Jensens inequality to get the result.

But secondly, what do I need the information $P(X\leq 0)=0$ for?

Comment: For a twice differentiable function concavity follows if the second derivative is $\le 0$, convexity follows from the opposit inequaly. $1/x$ is convex for $x>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f(x)$ is convex iff $f''(x)\geq0$. In this case, $(\frac{1}{x})''=\frac{2}{x^3}\geq0$, so $\frac{1}{x}$ is convex. When you apply $Jensen's inequality$, you should have 
the assumption $X$ and $f(X)$ is integrable, where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in this question. However when $X\gt0$,$E(X)=\infty$ or $E(\frac{1}{X})=\infty$, the conclusion is abvious to hold. Since $X$ is not greater than 0, $EX$ may not exist. This is how we use $X\gt0$

Comment: Just to make sure, that I understand it, so if $X \leq 0$, then the expected value will exists, or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh. I forgot. To ensure $(\frac{1}{x})''=\frac{2}{x^3}\geq0$, we should have $X>0$. What do you mean by "if $X\leq0$, then the expected value will exist". Actually, if $X\leq0$, then the expected value may not exist.

Comment: Okay, I will try again. If $X\leq 0$, then the expected value may not exists, and that is why we say $P(X\leq 0)=0?$

Comment: Yes. And if $X\leq0$, then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not convex. Then you can't apply Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Okay I get it now, thank you so much!